# External / internal precedence in css

Tags: html, css

I read all over internet that internal css (style section at `<head>`) has precendence over external css (through link). But that only works if I put `<link>` before `<style>` at `<head>` section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css" />
<style>
    body { background-image: url("images/bgdesert.jpg"); }
</style>
```

Here it is applied css in `<style>`.

But if I put `<style>` before `<link>`, the background-image applied is the one that is on "estilos.css".

```
<style>
    body { background-image: url("images/bgdesert.jpg"); }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css" />
```

All over internet, I always read that even if I put `<link>` after `<style>`, the precedence will be at `<style>`.
Am I wrong?

Comment: How CSS rules are applied depends on their specificity. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: You are geting the word "precedence" the wrong way. It means that you should use an external stylesheet is best practice. It doesn't mean it will take the rules from the external stylesheet always before the ones in <style>. The rules are always taken from the last line.

Comment: Nope, that is incorrect. The general rule is that whichever style is loaded last will take precedence(regardless of if it's in an external CSS file or placed within `style` tags), the exception to this is if you use the `!important` declaration(which you should pretty much never use), which will take precedence over any other non `!important` styles regardless of when they are loaded.

Comment: Cascade Layers look useful for controlling precedence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@layer

Answer (score 0):

Steven Bradley talks about [Precedence in CSS](http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).  The general rule of thumb when declaring your CSS is declare properties with the least specificity needed to style your elements.  By using this approach, it will make it easier for you to override a style by declaring the style more specific.

If you use the most specificity you may run into problems later and find yourself having to add unnecessary html in order to be able to add more specificity or you may find yourself falling back on using !important or declaring inline styles. Start with the least specificity and add more only as needed.

I think you also have to think about page load optimisation.  [Patrick Sexton does a great article](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/optimize-css-delivery.html) on how CSS usage impacts on page rendering/load. This is especially important now that page load is a factor in search engine ranking.